# Get excel file sheet names using CDatabase/ODBC driver

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, cdatabase

I am using OBDC to import data from some excel file using CDatabase and and excel drivers.
Code is something like this:

```
CString GetExcelDriver()
{
    TCHAR szBuf[2001];
    WORD cbBufMax = 2000;
    WORD cbBufOut;
    TCHAR *pszBuf = szBuf;
    CString sDriver;
    // Get the names of the installed drivers ("odbcinst.h" has to be included )
    if(!SQLGetInstalledDrivers(szBuf,cbBufMax,& cbBufOut))
        return _T("");

    // Search for the driver...
    do
    {
        if(_tcsstr( pszBuf, _T("Excel")) != 0 )
        {
            // Found !
            return pszBuf;
            break;
        }pszBuf = _tcschr( pszBuf, _T('\0')) + 1;
    }while( pszBuf[1] != _T('\0'));
    return _T("");
}
void ImportData()
{
    CString strExcelPath = _T("excel_file.xls");
    CString strSQL;
    CString strValue;
    strSQL.Format(_T("DRIVER={%s};DSN='';DBQ=%s")
                 , GetExcelDriver()
                 , strExcelPath);
    if(dbFile.Open(NULL,false,false,strSQL))
    {
        CRecordset rs(&dbFile);
        rs.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, _T("SELECT * FROM table_name"), CRecordset::readOnly);
        int nColumnCount = rs.m_nResultCols;
        while(!rs.IsEOF())
        {
            try
            {
                rs.GetFieldValue((short)0, strValue);
                rs.GetFieldValue((short)1, strValue);
                /*
                rs.GetFieldValue((short)2, strValue);
                rs.GetFieldValue((short)3, strValue);
                rs.GetFieldValue((short)4, strValue);
                .
                .
                .
                */
            }
            catch(CException* pEx)
            {
                // DB Exception
            }
            rs.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

But to do so, I need the excel sheet name(table_name). As long as I keep that hard-coded, it is fine but in case of user file, it will not work. After long hours of googling, not is found that could get me the sheet name. I would appretiate if any one may suggest a way to get the sheet name from the excel file.

Comment: Excel tables can be assigned names. Those names need not match the sheet name. You are asking about a solution to the wrong problem.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank for your input. If that be the case, how can I get the name of the table. I think there still should be some wayout to get the name of the first table.

Comment: Excel has an automation interface that allows you to discover virtually all document contents. Alternatively use a 3rd party library that understands .xls files.